# Obtener valor de <p> con js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy tratando de hacer algo muy simple, pero no consigo ver el fallo

Quiero obtener el valor de un `<p>` con **js** y aumentar su valor **+1**

```js
function aumentarPoint(){
  var demo = document.getElementById("demo").value;
  var puntos = demo + 1;
  demo.innerHTML = puntos;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo" onclick="aumentarPoint()">0</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo varios errores en tu código.

Para recuperar el valor dentro de una tag tienes que hacerlo mediante el `innerHTML`. Pero aunque el `.value` te hubiera funcionado, es ese el valor que guardas dentro de la variable `demo` en vez del elemento HTML, por lo que cuando intentabas modificar el `innerHTML` de este tampoco te habría funcionado.

Aquí te propongo una alternativa a tu función que espero que se ajuste a lo que necesitas:

> ```
> function aumentarPoint(){
>     var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
>     var demoValue = parseInt(demo.innerHTML);
>     var puntos = demoValue + 1;
>     demo.innerHTML = puntos;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Lo he conseguido de la siguiente manera

```js
var a = 0;
function aumentarPoint() {
  a = a + 1;
  document.getElementById("demo").textContent = a;
}
```

```html
<p onclick="aumentarPoint()" id="demo">0</p>
```

Comment: No tiene sentido que se lo sumes a la variable `a`, no la necesitas. Deberías de hacer `document.getElementById("demo").textContent = parseInt(document.getElementById("demo").textContent) +1`